# function parameters in time-driven trigger

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a function that should have two different behaviors depending on its parameters:

- If no parameter, do A
- Otherwise do B

If I just run the function selecting it on the script editor and clicking run it runs as expected. It does what is supposed to do without parameters. If I run it in a time driven trigger then nothing happens. I supposed that running the function in a trigger will set the parameters as undefined too. Am I missing something?

Here is the function code:

```
function logToday(sede) {
  var sheet=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('workedDays');
  var dateElement = new dateElement_();
  var hour=dateElement.hour()+":45";
  var monthYear=dateElement.month(); 
  var day=dateElement.dayInMonth();
  var dayName=dateElement.weekDayName();

  Logger.log("Running log Today with: "+sede);

  if(! sede)
  {

    sede="";hour="";
    sheet.appendRow([monthYear,dayName,day,sede,hour]);

  }
  else
  {
    var LastRow=new LastRow_(sheet);

    if(LastRow.getColValue("sede")=="")
    {
      LastRow.setColValue("sede",sede);
      LastRow.setColValue("Entered Hour",hour);
      if(dateElement.weekDay()==0 || dateElement.weekDay()==6 )colorWeekend(sheet);
      Logger.log(dateElement.weekDay());

    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Where is the function that is passing the argument? U will need to schedule that function instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when triggered, a function is given some parameters from the trigger. For exemple a time trigger every minute will return something like this:
{minute=58, day-of-week=1, timezone=UTC, week-of-year=7, second=20, day-of-month=10, month=2, year=2014, hour=10, authMode=full}

the function that do this test:

```
function test(e){
  SpreadsheetApp.openById("YOUR_SPREADSHEET_ID").appendRow([e]);
}
```

What you can do is: In your code instead of parsing a simple string as parameter you could pass to your function an object:

```
function passSedeArg(){
  var obj={"sede":"argument"}; // here "argument" must be changed for the old "sede" you where passing
  logToday(obj);
}

function logToday(obj) {
  var sheet=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('workedDays');
  var dateElement = new dateElement_();
  var hour=dateElement.hour()+":45";
  var monthYear=dateElement.month(); 
  var day=dateElement.dayInMonth();
  var dayName=dateElement.weekDayName();

  Logger.log("Running log Today with: "+sede);

  if(typeof obj.sede=="undefined") // no obj.sede argument where given
  {

    sede="";hour="";
    sheet.appendRow([monthYear,dayName,day,sede,hour]);

  }
  else // you have a obj.sede argument
  {
    var LastRow=new LastRow_(sheet);

    if(LastRow.getColValue("sede")=="")
    {
      LastRow.setColValue("sede",obj.sede);
      LastRow.setColValue("Entered Hour",hour);
      if(dateElement.weekDay()==0 || dateElement.weekDay()==6 )colorWeekend(sheet);
      Logger.log(dateElement.weekDay());

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I figured something like this and I was going to answer my own question, but your answer is much better. Thank you very much.